# how do i set cursor in the parent div which is contenteditable set to true but i have

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to set the caret cursor in the div which is contenteditable but the child is not contenteditable. I have this code where the cursor goes to child div whenever i click on the div

please help

```
var container = document.createElement('P');
                    container.id = 'Cakdlsfj';
                    container.className ='dragClass7 ';
                    container.style.zIndex = 500;
                    container.setAttribute('style','width:150px;height:20px; overflow:hidden ');
                    container.contentEditable = true;
                    container.style.position = 'absolute';
                    container.style.left = x+'px';
                    container.style.top = y+'px';
                    container.focus();
                    var div1 = document.createElement('DIV');
                    div1.setAttribute('style','background-color:gray; opacity:0.8; ');
                    **div1.contentEditable = false;**
                    div1.style.position = 'absolute';
                    div1.style.right = '20px';
                    div1.style.bottom = '0px';
                    div1.innerHTML = "A- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;        A+";
                    **container.appendChild(div1);
                    document.body.appendChild(container);**

                    div1.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){

                        div1.style.cursor = "pointer";
                    });

                    $('.dragClass7').draggable();
                    $('.dragClass7').resizable({autoHide:true});
```

check the lines in the bold...but i have the cursor set on child div by default.
even though it is not editable

Answer (score 1):

It's not totally clear if you're using jQuery here or not but using the native javascript focus method should set the caret to the `contentEditable` element like so:

```
var element = document.getElementById('Cakdlsfj');

element.focus();
```

It should be mentioned, you should do this **after** you've added the elements to the DOM.

Comment: OP *is* using jQuery, because there is a jQuery tag in his question.

Comment: I did notice the jQuery UI code but the OP seems to be adding elements to the DOM using native javascript which is why I was unsure.

Comment: I am using jquery code but creating new elements using javascript.